# Difference Between Oracle lnstant Client and Oracle Client

Tags: oracle, client, difference

What is the Difference Between Oracle lnstant Client and Oracle Client ? Could you explain me ? Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Oracle client comes with an installer and a lot of executable like
   sqlplus, tnsping, it's complete and huge.
2. Oracle Instant client is a basic lightweight client which can be
   unzipped in a location without any installation, it contains only the
   communication layer to be able to connect to oracle. It can be
   extended by adding for example sqlplus which ships as a separate
   executable. When using Instant Client, just unzip it to a location,
   set your ORACLE_HOME environment variable to this location and you
   are ready to go.

Comment: Regarding 1. When you run the installer you can select and unselect various components you like to install or not. So, the scale of "complete and huge" depends on your selections.

Comment: You're right, when I say complete and huge I talk about the size of the client source itself, a few MB for the instant client, a few hundred for the full client.

Comment: Which one do you prefer , instant or client for huge project? l

Comment: Instant Client 19.3 is a zip with 241 MB! The sole "oraociei19.dll" is 200 MB. "lightweight" is a generous compliment :-)

Comment: A little confused about the ORACLE_HOME part since the installation instructions do not mention that.https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/winx64-64-downloads.html#ic_winx64_inst